# How to lazy load HTML block (to avoid big DOM size), but also have web crawlers notice the lazy content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo, lazy-loading, pagespeed

I am using a sidebar [script](https://mmenujs.com/) to create a burger menu that pops a navigation bar with multiple links, once user clicks the burger.

I have many categories and subcategories that I link within that menu, so in my HTML, I have about 200 lines in the following pattern:

```
<li><span>A</span>
<ul><li><a href="/a/">Show A</a></li>
<li><a href="/a/1/">1</a></li>
<li><a href="/a/2/">2</a></li>
...
...
<li><a href="/a/20/">20</a></li>
....
....
<li><span>Z</span>
<ul><li><a href="/Z/">Show Z</a></li>
<li><a href="/z/1/">1</a></li>
<li><a href="/z/2/">2</a></li>
...
...
<li><a href="/z/20/">20</a></li>
```

Google Page Speed penalize my score for this for having a Big DOM size:

> Avoid an excessive DOM size: 1,215 elements
>
> Browser engineers recommend pages contain fewer than ~1,500 DOM
> elements. The sweet spot is a tree depth < 32 elements and fewer than
> 60 children/parent element. A large DOM can increase memory usage,
> cause longer style calculations, and produce costly layout reflows.

However, only a small percentage of my visitors bother to browse other page and actually click the burger menu to see all those links.

Therefore, the only solution I can think of, is perhaps to somehow lazy load all this HTML block, so it will not be considered as a big DOM size.

One option is to load it only when page loads, and another is to load it only when a user clicks the burger button. (the menu is hidden and being "pulled" once user clicks the burger.

- Will this be a good practice?
- What option should I choose?
- How do I actually do it?

**Another consideration is SEO - how will Google Crawler will see my pages if I do that:**

Currently, Google can see that from any page, users can reach to all those other pages. This menu serves as the main Navigation method.
But if I hide this menu from the initial HTML ouptut, I guess Google Bot might not consider those links any more, and might penalize the page for not having enough links in-site (burdens ease of navigation for visitors). though I'm not really sure about it.

Comment: anyone........?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to this one is not to worry (in fact lazy loading the content might be a bad idea in case your JavaScript fails)

1215 DOM nodes is high, but not a metric to worry about too much.

I have a page with 2080 DOM nodes (As I use inline SVGs) and it still scores 99 / 100 on page speed insights and works on a 5 year old smart phone just fine. [Link to my page speed results for reassurance](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fklu.io)

You aren't getting penalised for it, it is just an advisory item as long as your HTML is semantically correct. (as lots of DOM nodes is often a sign that your HTML needs refactoring, that's why they mention it).